# The contents of table in LaTeX are going off page

Tags: tables

I am very new to LaTeX. I made this table mostly copying online tables without any understanding. And why are the contents in column not centered? Don't mind some irrelevant packages that I might have added

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,subfig,url,hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\myname}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\myid}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\hwNo}{xxxxxxxxxx}
%%% END

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large LUMS}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large CS-210 Discrete Mathematics}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large \myname: \myid @lums.edu.pk}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
%--------------------- This is the title of the document. DO NOT CHANGE IT ------------------------

\title{CS-210 \hwNo}
\author{\myname \qquad Student ID: \myid}

%--------------------------------- AFTER Entering the Student and Homework Information, write your answers below  ----------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Problem 1}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{A}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline 
A  &  B  &  C &  $\overline{A}$   &  $\overline{B}$   &  $\overline{C}$  &   A$\cap$B  &   $\overline{A} \cap$C  &   A$ \cap \overline{B}$  &  $\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}$  &   A$\cap$B    $ \cup $ $\overline{A} \cap$C    & $ (\  ( \  A \cap B  )\   \cup  (\ \overline{A} \cap C  )\  )\ \complement $  &  $  (\ A \cap \overline{B}   )\  \cup   (\ \overline{A} \cap \overline{C} )\ $ \\ 
\hline\hline
  1&   1&  1 &       0               &   0 & 0 &1  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  & 0 \\
  1&  1 &  0 &         0             &   0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0\\
  1&  0 &  1 &           0           &   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  1&  1\\
  1&  0 &  0 &             0         &   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  1&  1\\
  0&  1 &  1 &         1             &   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0& 1 &  0&  0\\
  0&  1&   0&            1          &    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1& 0 &  1&  1\\
  0& 0  &  1 &             1         &   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0& 1 &  0 & 0\\
 0& 0  &   0&                1      &    1 &1  & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1& 0 &  1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134574.

Comment: To center the contents of a cell horizontally, use the `c` column type, not the `l` column type. Hint: `l` means "left-alignment"...

Answer (score 1):

A variant of your table which fits in the text width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{A}
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
  \toprule
  $A$ & $B$ & $C$ & $\overline{A}$ & $\overline{B}$ & $\overline{C}$ & $A\cap B$
      & $\overline{A}\cap C$ & $A\cap\overline{B}$
      & $\overline{A}\cap\overline{C}$
      & \makecell{$A\cap B$\\${}\cup\overline{A}\cap C$}
      & \makecell
          {$\big((A\cap B)$\\${}\cup(\overline{A}\cap C)\big)\complement$}
      & \makecell
          {$(A\cap\overline{B})$\\${}\cup(\overline{A}\cap\overline{C})$} \\ 
  \midrule
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you (a) get rid of all vertical lines (each lines takes up a bit of space, and 14 lines take up quite a bit of space!), (b) simplify the cell headers a bit (mostly, try to use math mode consistently), (c) use `c` rather than `l` as the column type for all 13 columns, and (d) employ a `tabular*` environment instead of the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large LUMS}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large CS-210 Discrete Mathematics}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large \myname: \myid @lums.edu.pk}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,subfig}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\myname}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\myid}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\hwNo}{xxxxxxxxxx}

\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
%%% END

%---- This is the title of the document. 
%---- DO NOT CHANGE IT --------------

\title{CS-210 \hwNo}
\author{\myname \qquad Student ID: \myid}

%----- AFTER Entering the Student and Homework 
%----- Information, write your answers below 

\begin{document}
\maketitle   
\section{Problem 1}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX calculate intercol. whitespace
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  % "2" is excessive
\caption{A}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{13}{c}}
\toprule
  $A$ 
& $B$ 
& $C$ 
& $\overline{A}$ 
& $\overline{B}$ 
& $\overline{C}$ 
& $A\cap B$ 
& $\overline{A} \cap C$ 
& $A \cap \overline{B}$ 
& $\overline{A} \cap \overline{C}$ 
& $A\cap B \cup \overline{A} \cap C$ 
& $ \overline{(A\cap B) \cup(\overline{A}\cap C)}$ 
& $ (A\cap\overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A}\cap\overline{C} )$ \\
\midrule % **not** \hline\hline
 1& 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 1& 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 0& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0& 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
 0& 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table is math, so it should be `array`. You can save much space, removing the added spaces after the parentheses and by reducing the padding between columns. Also the vertical rules can (and should) be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,fancyhdr,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,subfig,url,hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=14pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\myname}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\myid}{xxxxxxxx}
\newcommand{\hwNo}{xxxxxxxxxx}
%%% END

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large LUMS}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large CS-210 Discrete Mathematics}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\sffamily\bfseries\large \myname: \myid @lums.edu.pk}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
%--------------------- This is the title of the document. DO NOT CHANGE IT ------------------------

\title{CS-210 \hwNo}
\author{\myname \qquad Student ID: \myid}

%--------------------------------- AFTER Entering the Student and Homework Information, write your answers below  ----------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Problem 1}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{A}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{3.3pt}
\begin{array}{@{}*{13}{c}@{}}
\toprule
A  &  B  &  C &  \overline{A}   &  \overline{B}   &
\overline{C}  &   A\cap B  & \overline{A} \cap C  &
A \cap \overline{B}  &  \overline{A} \cap \overline{C} &
A\cap B \cup \overline{A} \cap C    &
((A \cap B)\cup(\overline{A}\cap C))^\complement  &
(A \cap \overline{B} )\cup (\overline{A} \cap \overline{C} ) \\ 
\midrule
  1&   1&  1 &       0               &   0 & 0 &1  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  & 0 \\
  1&  1 &  0 &         0             &   0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0\\
  1&  0 &  1 &           0           &   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  1&  1\\
  1&  0 &  0 &             0         &   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  1&  1\\
  0&  1 &  1 &         1             &   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0& 1 &  0&  0\\
  0&  1&   0&            1          &    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1& 0 &  1&  1\\
  0& 0  &  1 &             1         &   1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0& 1 &  0 & 0\\
 0& 0  &   0&                1      &    1 &1  & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1& 0 &  1 & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the setting of `headheight` and the use of `booktabs` for improving the quality of the table.

[image]